# OpenCL vs. CUDA with Mathematica

Tags: parallelization

I am thinking about using GPU programming with Mathematica using a MacBook Pro with a NVIDIA GPU. At [this page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCLLink/tutorial/Programming.html#7692900), the Mathematica documentation says "Programming OpenCL in the Wolfram Language is simple since the user need not write C wrapper code -- which can be quite verbose, difficult to understand, and hard to debug. Using *OpenCLLink* also guarantees compatibility as new versions of the standard are released." So what advantages might there be to programming in CUDA instead of OpenCL?

Comment: [This](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/10354/605) is a useful read.  In Mathematica, CUDALink has more useful functions that OpenCLLink.  Both the CUDALink and the OpenCLLink demos work fine for me on a 2012 MacBook Pro, but I didn't go deep into the technologies.  I think using them from Mathematica will be quite similar.